# How to know on which letter the user clicked in a WPF TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TextBlock` that presents a text. When the user clicks on the text, it is dynamically replaced with a `TextBox` (which is binded to the same data), effectively switching into "edit mode". This also significantly improves the performance.

The only caveat is that I am not able to know which part of the text the user clicked on. Therefore, the cursor always appears at the first position on the `TextBox`. Ideally, the cursor should appear in the same text position that the user clicked on.

Comment: Interestingly, this is a problem that Visual Studio chooses not to solve. If you click once on a highlighted file name in Solution Explorer (allowing you to rename the file), the text is highlighted, meaning you now need to click again within the textbox to place the caret. If you do not get an answer to your question, perhaps this could be a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperantly, The solution is quite simple and straightforward. However, It still uses TextBox and not TextBlock. The following method receives MouseButtonEventArgs from a mouse click event and the TextBox that triggered the event and return the text index on which the user clicked.

```
private int GetMouseClickPosition(MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs, 
                                  TextBox textBox1)
    {
        Point mouseDownPoint = mouseButtonEventArgs.GetPosition(textBox1);
        return textBox1.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(mouseDownPoint, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Create a TextBox
2. Create a Style named `LockedTextBoxStyle`

   - BorderThickness: 0
   - IsReadOnly: True
   - IsReadOnlyCaretVisible: True
   - Cursor: Arrow
3. Create a trigger for `IsKeyboardFocused`
     When true set the style to `LockedTextBoxStyle`

Since IsReadOnlyCaretVisible is set to true, I hope that would preserve the caret position. Haven't tested yet.

Comment: yout solution works well, but it requires using a `TextBox` and not a `TextBlock` in the read only mode and therefore loose the performance gains.
If I won't find another way, your solution is a great alternative, thanks.

By the way, `TextBox.IsReadOnlyCaretVisible` is a .Net 4.0 feature.

Comment: @Elad: Don't know what kind of performance you gain using a `TextBlock`. Might be you're using numerous TextBlocks.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I was wrestling with the same problem and this is the solution I came up with, crude though it may be, it seems to work just fine:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow.MainWindow"
...
...
<TextBlock MouseLeftButtonUp="TextBlock_OnMouseLeftButtonUp">Here is some Text</TextBlock>
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" Width="150"></TextBox>
```

Then, in the code behind:

```
private void TextBlock_OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;
    TextPointer tp = tb.GetPositionFromPoint(e.GetPosition(tb), false);

    int index = tp.GetLineStartPosition(0).GetOffsetToPosition(tp) - 1;

    TextBox1.Text = tb.Text;
    TextBox1.Focus();
    TextBox1.CaretIndex = index;

}
```