# Draw a static line between characters in a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox. I want the user to be able to click inside it; when he does, a red marker line should appear between the two characters closest to the click position, and remain here. The user could do that multiple times.

I'm new to WPF, but I guess, as in Winforms, I will have to hack a messy OnRender method. So far, it's okay.

What I'd really like to know is: how to get the two closest characters to the click position?

I was about to do a pixel check but it seems pretty heavy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253275/how-to-know-on-which-letter-the-user-clicked-in-a-wpf-textblock

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well I found what I wanted to do, and it's way simpler than I thought (even though FINDING the actual way was a pain).

Just add this handler to your textbox's SelectionChanged event:

```
private void placeMarker(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // txt_mark is your TextBox
    int index = txt_mark.CaretIndex;
    // I don't want the user to be able to place a marker at index = 0 or after the last character
    if (txt_mark.Text.Length > first && first > 0)
    {
        Rect rect = txt_mark.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(first);

        Line line = new Line();
        // If by any chance, your textbox is in a scroll view,
        // use the scroll view's margin instead
        line.X1 = line.X2 = rect.Location.X + txt_mark.Margin.Left;
        line.Y1 = rect.Location.Y + txt_mark.Margin.Top;
        line.Y2 = rect.Bottom + txt_mark.Margin.Top;

        line.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        line.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
        line.StrokeThickness = 1;
        line.Stroke = Brushes.Red;

        // grid1 or any panel you have
        grid1.Children.Add(line);
        // set the grid position of the line to txt_mark's (or the scrollview's if there is one)
        Grid.SetRow(line, Grid.GetRow(txt_mark));
        Grid.SetColumn(line, Grid.GetColumn(txt_mark));
    }
}
```

You might want to add some kerning or simply increase the font size for the markers not to ruin readability.

Answer (score -1):

You could try:
`textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(point, true);`

Comment: Please make more of an effort when answering on this website. You could have quite easily provided an explanation of the method and a link to further documentation for example. Previously I would have down voted for a single line answer, so I hope you appreciate this more gentle approach of encouragement.

Comment: @Sheridan Perhaps you are right but I find the answer to be quite self explanatory and I do believe that a simple search would give all those answers (even without my answer to be honest). If I have offended anyone, I am sorry.

Comment: It really is not about being self explanatory, or offending anyone. It is about the fact that Stack Overflow is a quality website, where users know that they can come to get good quality answers to their questions. As a senior user, I was merely requesting that you improve your answer in an attempt to maintain the high standards normally found on this website. It's unfortunate that you don't feel the same way.

Comment: @Sheridan I guess I just don't like being fed the answer with a spoon but rather to try working it out myself with some assistance  and I assume others do too. Maybe that's my fault.

Comment: @o_weisman On StackOverflow, answer means answer, not hint. Comments are suited for these.